# Running sh script once per day

Tags: sh

I'm working on a `sh` script which starts at boot and needs to execute a command once per day [moving it to cron is not an option].

My idea is to create an infinite loop and check the current and and if the time is "right" execute the command.

```
while true
do 
currenttime=$(date +%H:%M)
if [ "$currenttime" = "23:00" ]; then
  echo 'IT IS TIME !!!!!!!!!'
fi

sleep 1h
done
```

The problem is the script may start at any time (i.e. 9:14) so if it executes every hour the script will run at 23:14.

Any idea how to make sure it runs once?

Comment: Well you can decrease the sleep time to 30 min. This will allow your script run every 30 min

Answer (score 0):

Since the time resolution you're showing us is 1 minute, you could prepend another loop waiting for the full hour, checking the time each minute. After that you can proceed to the main loop that sleeps for 1 hour each turn.

**EDIT**

```
while true
do
  currenttime=$(date +%M)
  echo SYNC $currenttime
  if [[ "$currenttime" == "00" ]]; then
    break
  fi
  sleep 1m
done
while true
do
  currenttime=$(date +%S:%M)
  echo WAIT $currenttime
  if [[ "$currenttime" == "23:00" ]]; then
    echo 'IT IS TIME !!!!!!!!!'
  fi
  sleep 1h
done
```

However, a quick test showed that the right moment could be missed. For this test I used seconds instead of minutes, and minutes instead of hours, and it jumps right over the "00" seconds. You should think of a more elaborated algorithm making sure that the special moment is not missed.

Comment: How would I do something like that?  Thanks